# What is the algorithm behind Snapseeds "healing" tool?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Using the "healing" tool of the popular image editing app Snapseed you can make people disappear in an image and cleanly fill the remaining space with the background color and pattern. Interestingly this does not leave ugly edges you would expect from simple copy-move algorithms and instead produces smooth transitions even when filling space with complicated patterns like gravel and scrub. How does this work?

Comment: This question is mostly opinion based and probably will be closed soon.

Comment: How long does it take to perform this action? Maybe you can conclude how complicated the algorithm is.

Comment: You can read when did this feature was added and remove from your options all the algorithms created after this date. (The app was created in 2011)

Comment: You are probably looking for *"Content Aware Fill"* or *"Inpainting"* https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question that I asked myself a while ago, but without finding an answer...
One day, however, I was using GIMP's Healing tool (very similar to Snapseed's) and not knowing how to use it I took a look at the documentation (https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-heal.html) and I found that the algorithm is based on a scientific paper by Todor Georgiev:

http://www.tgeorgiev.net/Invariant.pdf

I think that the only difference between Gimp and Snapseed algorithm is to decide the point (or points) where the similar image to replace is picked, copied and then pasted on the areas that you want to cover (in Gimp you can choose *where*, while in Snapseed everything it's automatic).

Generally, this technique is called "*inpainting*", and in Photoshop it appears also as "*content-aware fill*" but GIMP specifically uses "*Poisson editing*". If you search it on Google you can find a lot of examples and explanations.

[https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf)

https://direns.mines-paristech.fr/Sites/Complex-analysis/Poisson%20Image%20Editing/Poisson%20Image%20Editing.pdf